# Script to clean log files does not delete them

Tags: linux, scripting

Could someone explain to me why this script does not delete /var/logmessages and /var/log/wtmp files? I found it on tldp.org tutorial

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG_DIR=/var/log
cd $LOG_DIR
cat /dev/null > messages
cat /dev/null > wtmp
echo "Logs cleaned up"
exit
```

After executing it, I checked /var/log directory and messages and wtmp are still there with the "old" logs.

Why is that happening?

Comment: The script should work, unless you don't have write permission on these files.

Comment: Well, i'm using root account now! :(

Comment: (I edited the question to try to make it clear, since it is in the process of being closed)

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: Thank you for helping me edit my post.

Comment: This is a still a yes/no answerable question ("yes, someone explain"/"no, nobody can explain"). Are you really just interested in **finding** someone who can explain something, instead of the actual explanation?

Comment: I'm just being nice and polite here, man!  I meant if someone could help me out, that's what i thought.

Comment: why are you even doing this?  why not just use logrotate?  or roll your own log rotation script?  deleting log files and wtmp login records looks like you're trying to hide something - from the real admins of the server or from your employer, perhaps.

Comment: This was the script i found on this site: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/sha-bang.html#EX1
I just want to test it.

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely have to clean a log file, you have to do it as sudo/root and restart the syslog daemon. The adm group only lets you read but not write (some) log files.

Be aware that in a Unix system a file only gives up the space being used/ceases to exist when it is not used anymore, hence the need for a syslog restart because if you are deleting a file using up all your log partition you won't see the space freed *until* you restart the syslog daemon. Likewise, syslog will be still sending logs to the already "deleted" files, and not to the new ones created with your stdout redirection (">") until you restart it.

About the wtmp and messages, let´s see their permissions by default:

```
$ls -la /var/log/messages /var/log/wtmp
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 818148 Apr 14 07:15 /var/log/messages
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root utmp 284928 Apr 14 07:37 wtmp
```

So the script should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG_DIR=/var/log
cd $LOG_DIR
sudo cat /dev/null > messages
sudo cat /dev/null > wtmp
sudo service rsyslogd restart
echo "Logs cleaned up"
exit 0
```

At the end of the day, the syslog daemon also (re)creates the /var/log/messages file with the right permissions, so actually I would prefer to do it as:

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG_DIR=/var/log
cd $LOG_DIR
sudo rm messages
sudo sh -c 'cat /dev/null > wtmp'
sudo service rsyslogd restart
echo "Logs cleaned up"
exit 0
```

A warning: be careful with the scripts you run. You should not overwrite /var/log/wtmp in a production system. You want to have an history of the users who logged into it.

Comment: I created a new script with the same as what you wrote in your comment but it didn't work too. You could see that on my first post. (I edited it)

It said: rm: cannot remove ‘wtmp’: No such file or directory

Comment: My fault, corrected. wtmp is not automatically (re)created upon restart, only messages.

Comment: This won't work, `sudo cat /dev/null > wtmp` as the redirection to `wtmp` is performed before (and outside) the `sudo`